# Cross Browser Coded UI doesn't work with the latest version of FireFox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

I used the BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser feature in order to run my Coded UI test cross over different browsers. However it is failing.

I uninstalled the latest versions of FireFox (26) and Chrome (32.0.1700.76) and re-install older versions and it is working again.

Do you have any idea why cross browser of the Coded UI doesn't work with the latest versions of FireFox and Chrome?

How can I fix the issue (except installing an older version)? Is there any work around?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This article explains cross browser testing with COdedUI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx

Specifically "Install the Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing Visual Studio extension."

Which can be found here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d

Or you can search for them with nuget inside visual studio

Note: Selenium does not support the lastest versions of firefox and chrome
"
Supported Browser versions 
The following versions of browsers have been verified and are supported:
Firefox 23.
Latest version of Chrome (version 29.0.1547.59 m as of 9/4/2013)
"

Comment: It seems that you didn't pay attention to my question. I have already installed Selenium Component and all required steps. Cross browser Coded UI doesn't work with the latest versions of FireFox and Chrome anymore. As soon as I installed older versions of FF and Chrome, the same code started working.

Comment: Sorry BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser still exists in vanilla CodedUI, which has issues with versions of firefox past 3 and chrome past an early version as well. It was not clear that you actually had the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found only FF 24.0 version work for me.
The latest version does not.

For chrome, the latest version also works.